# Synchronized instances and Synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Assume that we have a class with two synchronized blocks :

```
class A{

public synchronized void methodA{

// Do Something
}


public synchronized void methodB{

// Do Something
}

}
```

Assume that we have two threads `t1` and `t2` sharing the same instance of class `A`. If `t1` will invoke `methodA` using its instance of class `A` and at the same time `t2` will invoke `methodB` using the same instance of class `A` that is used by `t1`. According to my understanding, `t2` will be blocked from using the synchronized method `methodB` , even if `t1` is using only `methodA`. This is because every object has one lock and this lock is acquired by `t1`. Is that correct ? If yes, can we conclude the same if we have two synchronized blocks instead ?

Comment: Placing `synchronized` in the declaration of an instance method is the same as if you surrounded the entire method body in a `synchronized (this) { ... }` block.

Comment: `This is because every object has one lock and this lock is acquired by t1. Is that correct ?` Yes, each instance of an object has one lock, using the synchronized keyword on a method uses that instance lock.  I don't really understand your second question... can you give an example?

Comment: @markspace Kindly see the first two code blocks provided by rzwitserloot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

This:

```
synchronized void foo() {
  code();
}
```

is simply shorthand for:

```
void foo() {
  synchronized (this) {
    code();
  }
}
```

For the same reason having a public field is generally a really bad idea, having a public lock (and `this` is, usually, 'public', in the sense that code from outside the package has access to it) is a really bad idea. It's usually better to do:

```
class Example {
  private final Object lock = new Object[0];

  public void foo() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      code();
    }
  }
}
```

**if** you make the lock public (as in, use `synchronized`, or otherwise lock on something code outside of your direct control has access to), you **must** document this, and be very detailed about what you promise to do and not do with that lock in future updates.

Comment: (and to clarify `new Object[0]` - `new Object()` is usually just as good, but the 0-len array variant serializes. Not that you should use java's baked in serialization mechanism, but if you are - `new Object[0]` it is.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer to your question (rzwitzerloot did a fine job of that,) but

> `t2` will be blocked from using the synchronized method `methodB` , even if `t1` is using only `methodA`.

We don't really ever need `synchronized` to prevent two threads from calling the same method. That's not the point. Methods are immutable. No harm can come from two threads being in the same method *per se.* The trouble comes when two (or more) threads access the same *data.*

If two threads call the same instance method on two different objects, that's probably OK. If two threads call two different methods on the same single object, *that's* when we want `synchronized` to prevent any thread from seeing the object in an invalid state (or worse, to prevent any thread from *leaving* the object in an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
public final class A
{
    public synchronized void methodA
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    
    public synchronized void methodB
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public final class A
{
    public void methodA
    {
        synchronized( this )
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
    
    public void methodB
    {
        synchronized( this )
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, you assumption is correct, you can have two `synchronized` blocks instead of `synchronized` method to achieve the same effect.

The important thing is that the `synchronize` statements in both methods use the *same* object as 'argument'! In this case it is the instance itself, therefore it is easy.

But I have also seen this in some code:

```
public final class A
{
    /* DO NOT DO THIS */
    private static final Object m_LockForA = new Object [0];
    private static final Object m_LockForB = new Object [0];

    public void methodA
    {
        synchronized( m_LockForA )
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
    
    public void methodB
    {
        synchronized( m_LockForB )
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

This will work somehow (and perhaps it is even intended to work exactly in that way …) but completely different from your original code.

Comment: Not sure I agree with `/* DO NOT DO THIS */` there are valid reasons to use more than one lock.  It can be done incorrectly of course but any code can be used incorrectly.

Comment: I agree with [comment by markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980680/synchronized-instances-and-synchronized-blocks#comment134009576_75980842). I would have up-voted except for that "DO NOT DO THIS" admonition. I suggest you rework this Answer to show on option for multiple locks being appropriate (and possible) where a single lock per object may not be.

Comment: @BasilBourque – Have a look to the sample code … the original code protects the data of the *instance*, while the sample uses locks that may work to protect *class data*. A completely different intention (if done intentionally!).

Comment: This is called lock splitting and is a technique to increase concurrency.

Comment: @pveentjer – To call it "lock splitting" you (or I in this case) need to specify the particular properties of `A` to be protected by which lock/modified by which method. In the shown over-generalised form you can't decide whether it is useful or crap. And most probably you would use *instance* objects, not *static* ones for the locks if "lock splitting" is your goal.

Comment: I agree. You don't want to lock on a static field (I didn't see the static part).